# DataTables - Server Side Pagination issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, pagination, datatables

I have been doing a lot of research as to why my server side script will not handle pagination.

I have already seen a bunch of posts, where people have the same issue, and its typicaly caused by the JSON Response that the script gives:

here is my json data response from my server side script.

```
//set at the top of file
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

$json_data = array(
    "draw"              => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
    "recordsTotal"      => intval( $totalData ),
    "recordsFiltered"   => intval( $totalFiltered ),
    "data"              => $Data
 );
```

here is my initialization of the DataTable

```
    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        scrollY: 500,
        paging: true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": "50",
        "order": [[0,'asc'],[1,'asc'],[2,'asc']],
        "ajax": {
            url : "php/Inventory/Actions/LoadCatalog.php?Commodity="+Commodity+"&Make="+Make,
            type: "post",  // method  , by default get
            error: function(){  // error handling
            }
        },
        "aoColumns":[
            {"mData": "Commodity"},
            {"mData": "Make"},
            {"mData": "PartNumber"},
            {"mData": "Description"},
            {"mData": "Condition", "sClass": "myCenter"},
            {"mData": "Qty", "sClass": "myCenter"},
            {"mData": "From"}
        ],
        "bFilter": false,
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            //alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
            console.log(oSettings.json);
            LoopData();
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Now the first time i load the table, every thing seems to be fine...
my JSON response:

```
draw : 1
recordsFiltered : 3059
recordsTotal : 3059
```

the footer of table displays

```
Showing 1 to 50 of 3,059 entries
```

NOW! if i click the next button, it all falls apart.

```
draw : 2
recordsFiltered : 3059
recordsTotal : 3059
```

And my footer:

```
Showing 0,501 to 3,059 of 3,059 entries
```

at this point i cannot click next again. (it wont do anything..)
I can click the first, and previous button, and it will return to the first page, with everything appearing to be okay.

to to clarify, in my server side script i set the $totalData and $totalFiltered like so

```
//$sql = my selector statement with all the total records (3,5059)
$sql = "
SELECT `Inventory`.`Commodity`, `Inventory`.`Make`, 
`Inventory`.`PartNumber`, `Inventory`.`Model`, 
`Inventory`.`Condition`,SUM(`Inventory`.`Qty`) as `SumQty`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Contacts`.`Name` SEPARATOR '<hr>') as `From`
FROM `Inventory`
INNER JOIN `Purchasing` ON `Inventory`.`JobNumber` =                 
`Purchasing`.`JobNumber`
INNER JOIN `Contacts` ON `Purchasing`.`Vendor` = `Contacts`.`id`
WHERE `Inventory`.`Saved` = '1' AND `Purchasing`.`Status` != 'Pending'
GROUP BY `Inventory`.`Commodity`, `Inventory`.`Make`, 
`Inventory`.`PartNumber`, `Inventory`.`Model`, `Inventory`.`Condition`
";
$InvData=mysql_query($sql);
$totalData = mysql_num_rows($InvData);

//then again i update my sql, including my filters and WITHOUT limit set
// my filters are nothing - i dont do a search or any other kind filter so 
   the data will be the same | total records (3,5059)
$InvData=mysql_query($sql)
$totalFiltered = mysql_num_rows($InvData);
```

Comment: where are you controlling the number of rows being sent back? You should be sending back rows 0 -49, on the second request, send back rows 50 -99. Its up to you to take the information sent by the client and figure out what to send back.  Honestly, if you are only talking about 3500 to 5000 rows, I would send them all back and do client side paging unless you are on a real slow network

Comment: @Bindrid
Thank you for your response! I was under the impression that i was controlling the rows sent back by returning "recordsTotal" & "recordsFiltered". What must i return in order to state i am at 50-99?
Thank you!

PS. this example is with a small work order, but it will eventually be around 40k records or more.